# NSubstitute creating two instances of substituted instance

Tags: c#, tdd, xunit, nsubstitute

I've got a base ApiController for my controllers to inherit:

```
public BaseApiController(ILogger logger) : ApiController
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public BaseApiController(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger.ForContext("SomeContext");
    }
}
```

And a simple controller that's inheriting from the base controller:

```
public SomeController : BaseApiController
{
    public SomeController(ILogger logger) : base(logger)
    { }

    public IHttpActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        _logger.Information("Start doing something...");

        //Do stuff...

        _logger.Information("End doing something...");

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

I've created a simple test for the controller using Xunit and Nsubstitute:

```
public void SomeAction_ReturnsOk()
{
    //Arrange
    var logger = Substitute.For<ILogger>();
    var controller = new SomeController(logger) {
        Request = Substitute.For<HttpRequestMessage>()
    };

    //Act
    var result = controller.SomeAction();

    //Assert
    logger.ReceivedWithAnyArgs().Information(Arg.Any<string>());
}
```

When executing the test case, it fails stating that it has received zero calls to the logger.Information() method. When debugging the _receivedCalls property **(on the substituted ILogger)**, if the debug context is within the test case itself it is showing a single call to the `logger.ForContext()` method **(which was called on the base class constructor)**, however when looking at the debug within the context of the controller.SomeAction() method, the same `_receivedCalls` property shows the two calls to `logger.Information()` as would be expected but not the call to `ForContext()`.

So it appears to me that for some reason Nsubstitute is creating two separate instances of the substitute class, one in the context of the base controller and one in the actual controller - why is this and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stub the `ForContext` return like this:

```
public void SomeAction_ReturnsOk()
{
    //Arrange
    var logger = Substitute.For<ILogger>();
    logger.ForContext(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(logger);
    var controller = new SomeController(logger) {
        Request = Substitute.For<HttpRequestMessage>()
    };

    //Act
    var result = controller.SomeAction();

    //Assert
    logger.Received().Information(Arg.Any<string>());
}
```

I change the assert to:

```
logger.Received().Information(Arg.Any<string>());
```

OR:

```
logger.ReceivedWithAnyArgs().Information("");
```

Comment: I've stubbed the ForContext but it still doesn't work? Any ideas?

Comment: You've hit the nail on the head though, removing the ForContext() call and just assigning _logger = logger in the constructor works so it appears the ForContext isn't working now?

Comment: Ignore me, the method is ForContext(string, object) - I had it stubbed as ForContext(Any.Args<string>(), Any.Args<string>()), not ForContext(Any.Args<string>(), Any.Args<object>()) and the Returns() method wasn't working. Great shout, thanks for your help.